# How to use select2.js with multiple ids

Tags: php, jquery-select2

the select2-multiple works when placed only once. but i've a page where i need to place select2-multiple  multiple times.

as select2 assigns particular id to the div i.e select-multiple, i can't change that.

Works fine ->

```
<select id="select2-multiple" data-plugin="select2" class="form-control" multiple>
```

when placing multiple, won't work-> (only the first one works)

```
<select id="select2-multiple" data-plugin="select2" class="form-control" multiple>
<select id="select2-multiple" data-plugin="select2" class="form-control" multiple>
<select id="select2-multiple" data-plugin="select2" class="form-control" multiple>
```

i know because multiple id overlapping. but i can't change the id as select2 will not work on different id other than "select2-multiple"

Any Solution ?

Comment: Can you also assign `name`? Different names on each select element.

Comment: yes i can assign. but still due to same id, the select2 will not work.  only the fiest one works

Comment: `i can't change the id as select2 will not work on different id other than "select2-multiple"` given that, you can actually manipulate the `select2 plugin` on your own script and so you could assign unique elements.

Comment: _“but i can't change the id as select2 will not work on different id other than "select2-multiple"”_ - what are you even talking about …? The examples on https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage don’t even use any IDs at all. (Is it possible that you are under the wrong impression that `$('#select2-multiple').select2()` was the only way to initialize this …?)

Comment: using class instead of id is working... you should try that

Comment: here is an example tutorial  https://youtu.be/gTNQOxvuUv0

Answer (score 1):

You cannot initialize two select2 for same ID therefore use class attribute to initialize select2.

HTML

```
<select class="form-control select2-multiple" multiple>
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control select2-multiple" multiple>
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.select2-multiple').select2();
});
```

Working demo: https://jsbin.com/misubazino